# Vanilla JS query selector not grabbing the elements in the dom?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to use `document.querySelectorAll('a')` in this mobile site: https://pwa.www.1800flowers.com, but its only grabbing 3 anchor elements. Its weird because by looking at the console, there's many anchor elements. I wanted to grab a specific one, but just doing this simple query selector, its only grabbing 3.

Any ideas on why this is happening? Or if I wanted to go about grabbing a specific anchor element, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: Thanks for your insights @brk, but if you read the question, you'd understand what this post is about, and a code isn't something I needed to post, but instead needed to understand how to get a specific element from a website. If it was a code I needed to post, I would've done so :\

Comment: Well how are you calling the code? Unclear when you are trying to read the links or where.

Comment: @epascarello this isn't my website, I'm trying to see how I can get anchor object from the inspect element console using `document.querySelectorAll('a')`.

Comment: You can see that they overwrote `document.querySelectorAll` when you just type the method name in the console.

Comment: Thanks @epascarello! yeah, i can see that. Rafael, provided me the answer to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are using iron pages
https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-pages

In my searches, I found something like:

```
this.$$('a');
```

returns:

```
(435) [a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a#radio-icon, a#cart-icon, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, …]
```

Comment: wow thanks! i wouldn't even know how to search for this lol. thanks again!

Comment: No reason to use this. `$$("a")` is chrome's shortcut

Comment: @epascarello interesting. I've never seen `$$` before lol. Is there like something like that to vanilla js? I'm trying to test the site but it seems like `$$` isn't working.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference